# C# timer - Getting the 'Method name expected' error

Tags: c#, syntax-error

When I try to set the tick event of my timer, and use the method, I get this error. What's going wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace QueueSimulation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
        }

        public void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessCustomers CustomerQueue = new ProcessCustomers(); // create the CustomerQueue

            System.Windows.Forms.Timer queueTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            queueTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(customerArriveChooser.Value*1000);   
            queueTimer.Tick += new ElapsedEventHandler(CustomerQueue.Arrive()); 

            CustomerQueue.Arrive();
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // put code here to break out of the program
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        int timeInQueue;
    }

    public class ProcessCustomers
    {   
        public void Arrive(){}

        public void Leave(){}
    }

    public class Server
    {
        bool servingStatus = false; // true for serving, false for not serving
    }

    public class Queue
    {
        Customer[] queue = new Customer[49]; // initialise a queue (array) capable of holding 50 customers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean to use the method *name*, not call it and use the return value:

```
queueTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(CustomerQueue.Arrive);
```

Since the return value of `Arrive` is not a delegate type, you can't use it.

Note that the event handler signature should match the delegate signature - in the case of `Tick`, it is `EventHandler`:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(
    Object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

So, your `Arrive` method should take these two parameters:

```
public void Arrive(Object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Comment: But then I get No overload for 'Arrive' matches delegate 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'

Comment: @Alex - because it doesn't have the right parameters for a `Tick` event handler. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now I'm getting "No overload for 'Arrive' matches delegate 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler'"

Comment: I've changed Object to object now. I'm getting  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: That's because `Tick` event is of type `EventHandler`, not `ElapsedEventHandler`. Answer updated. Look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`ElapsedEventHandler` is the handle for `System.Timer` not for `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

the event must look like this:

```
queueTimer.Tick += new ElapsedEventHandler(queueTimer_Tick); 


void queueTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerQueue.Arrive();
}
```

Comment: Just change System.Windows.Forms.Timer queueTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
 to System.Timers.Timer queueTimer  = new System.Timers.Timer();